# How can i update a checkbox field on the opportunity based on criteria in the opportunity team members section

Tags: opportunity, field-update, opportunity-teams

I need to update a checkbox field on the oppty called IsTrue when there is an opportunity team member added (so, when an opportunity team member is not blank). Is this possible via workflow or process builder? if so how would it be done?

Comment: You should take a look at Trailhead for how to utilize the process builder. Short answer is yes, this is possible without a high amount of effort. Start here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=process%20builder - also if you do not need to cascade automation from this field update you are likely better off using a formula field.

Comment: It feels weird to me to close this as a duplicate. The potential duplicate gives an argument for why to use workflow over Process Builder, but this question is about how to create the PB or Workflow. I think this is better described as off-topic for not describing/showing a specific issue (but rather asking for help on basics). So, to Rachel, I'd suggest looking through Trailhead to learn how to create a workflow or Process Builder, work on achieving your requirement on your own, and then ask a new question if you get stuck on a specific part.